# how to pass command line arguments to a python script running in docker

Tags: docker

I have a python file called `perf_alarm_checker.py`, this python file requires two command line arguments: `python perf_alarm_checker.py -t something -d something`, the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Base image
FROM some base image

ADD perf_alarm_checker.py /perf-test/

CMD python perf_alarm_checker.py
```

How to pass the two command line arguments, `-t` and `-d` to `docker run`? I tried `docker run -w /perf-test alarm-checker -t something -d something` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot use `-t` and `-d` as you intend, as those are options for `docker run`.

- `-t` starts a terminal.
- `-d` starts the docker container as a daemon.

For setting environment variables in your Dockerfile use the `ENV` command.

```
ENV <key>=<value>
```

See the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

Another option is to pass environment variables through `docker run`:

```
docker run ... -e "key=value" ...
```

See the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables).

Those environment variables can be accessed from the `CMD`.

```
CMD python perf_alarm_checker.py -t $ENV1 -d $ENV2
```

Answer (score 63):

Use an ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD and then you can use command line options in the docker run like in your example.

`ENTRYPOINT ["python", "perf_alarm_checker.py"]`

Comment: This should be the correct answer... Not sure why the other answer is marked as green...