# Passing argument to python application running on docker

Tags: python, docker

I want to pass argument to python file app.py while running its docker image using command :

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 python_app https://github.com/abc/repo
```

where python_app is image of my application and `https://github.com/abc/repo` is the argument which I want to pass. But when I run docker image using above command my container exits with error :`No such directory or file found`

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7.13
MAINTAINER xyz "abc@hotmail.com"
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py","https://github.com/abc/repo"]
```

I think my param2 in `CMD` is treated an argument for docker image rather than argument for python application.

Answer (score 1):

td;lr use ENTRYPOINT `["python", "app.py"]` then you can pass parameters to the `docker run`

see answer here: [how to pass command line arguments to a python script running in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766638/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-python-script-running-in-docker) td

Comment: python: can't open file 'https://github.com/abc/config-example': [Errno 2] No such file or directory....I am still getting this error

Comment: does the script run when passed that argument. this looks like a python error not docker

Comment: it runs perfectly fine when I make it static string instead of passing it as argument

Comment: ok, forget docker for a second, run `app.py  'github.com/abc/config-example'` in the shell. does that run error free?

Comment: yes , without docker also it runs perfectly fine, that's why I thought it might be docker issue or something with argument