# Putting a python script into a docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am attempting to put an existing python function into a docker container. The python code takes a CSV file (that will be in the same directory as the dockerfile) as input data and does some calculations. The py file looks like this and is named "PracticeDeploy.py":

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from OptimizationFunction import main_barrel

# Read in model
gbrModel = pickle.load(open('/src/ValDiffGBR.pkl', 'rb'))
file_name = str(input())
data=pd.read_csv('/src/'+file_name)
new_data = data.dropna(how='any')
preds = main_barrel(gbrModel, new_data)
```

Within my docker directory, I already have a subfolder which contains my first dockerfile with all libraries installed. Also in my directory, I have the py file, the CSV, and the model I import in the above py file. I am now trying to build another dockerfile that will take the CSV name as input and then run the python code.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM [my repository] as builder
ARG DATA_FILE

RUN mkdir src
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src

ENTRYPOINT ["PracticeDeploy.py"]
```

I build like this:

```
sudo docker build --rm -f Dockerfile -t "first_docker" --build-arg DATA_FILE='/src/[csv_name].csv' .
```

I attempt to run like this:

```
sudo docker run --rm first_docker
```

However I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create 
failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process 
caused "exec: \"PracticeDeploy.py\": executable file not 
found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Should I only insert arguments when running? Am I approaching this correctly? I am very new to docker and am completely stumped.

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["./PracticeDeploy.py"]` should work.

Comment: Try adding "python" to your Entrypoint. Your PracticeDeploy.py is not executable nor does it has `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: Someone else has used CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT to run a python file with success here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766638/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-python-script-running-in-docker. Here is a blog on how to dockerize your python, they also use CMD: https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**CMD SOLUTION**

I would recommend switching from Entrypoint to CMD

```
CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]
```

This method can be seen in depth here: https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application

Some more complexity (flags etc) can also be handled with CMD as can be seen here : [how to pass command line arguments to a python script running in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766638/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-python-script-running-in-docker)

**ENTRYPOINT SOLUTION**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

This style of solution is explained in depth here:
https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/08/21/container-entrypoint/

**The difference between the two (if you're curious and don't know)**

**CMD** commands can be overwritten from the command line. **CMD** is effectively the default value of your container's command.

**ENTRYPOINT** commands are not overwritten from the command line.

**CMD** and **ENTRYPOINT** are similar, but I prefer command because it enables me to change the flags or command at run time if preferred, while keeping the same dockerfile that can be run without a command if desired.

Here is a longer form discussion of the difference:
http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Comment: First link on runnable.com is dead. Take this link: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/