# No such file or directory error while running Docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I am learning Docker concept and trying to make a Docker image of my project. I have installed Docker Desktop for Windows and build the image successfully by using below command:

```
docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME} .
```

But when I run following command `docker run ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}` I am getting following file not found error:

> D:\Projects\AI360\deep_auto_backbar_api>docker run dsbyprateekg:prateek_gupta
>   python3: can't open file '/Prepare_Dataset/server_engine/server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My project structure is looks like:

[image]

And my Dockerfile.txt has following instructions:

```
FROM python: 3.6-stretch
MAINTAINER PrateekG

# install build utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential

# check our python environment
RUN python3 version RUN pip3 --version

# Installing python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy all the files from the project's root to the working directory 
COPY Prepare_Dataset/ .

# Running Python Application
CMD ["python3", "/Prepare_Dataset/server_engine/server.py"]
```

I suspect I am missing something related to file path. Please see my Dockerfile and my project structure and help me to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: please avoid to user external images and when possible use text instead of screenshots. please have a look at my edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59497389/revisions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `COPY Prepare_Dataset/ .` this will copy the content of the directory, not the directory itself so 
 `CMD` path become invalid `/Prepare_Dataset/server_engine/server.py`.

You need to use

```
COPY Prepare_Dataset/ ./Prepare_Dataset/
```

so when you copy you can verify

```
Step 5/7 : COPY Prepare_Dataset/ ./Prepare_Dataset/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c5c15c23f65
Step 6/7 : RUN ls | grep "Prepare_Dataset"
 ---> Running in 54147bd4740c
Prepare_Dataset
```

Better to keep convention to avoid such error in future.

```
# SEt workdirectory
WORKDIR /app
# Now it will copy to /app/
COPY Prepare_Dataset/ ./Prepare_Dataset
CMD ["Prepare_Dataset/server_engine/server.py"]
```

You can verify you problem using below steps.

```
COPY Prepare_Dataset/ .
#You will see the content but not the directory
RUN ls /
```

You will not able to see the directory but you can grep the any file in it.

```
Step 5/7 : COPY Prepare_Dataset/ .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4eec046c860
Step 6/7 : RUN ls | grep "Prepare_Dataset"
 ---> Running in 23e4b2aab3d1
The command '/bin/sh -c ls | grep "Prepare_Dataset"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case I had to change the line separators from **cr/lf** (Windows) to **lf** (Unix/Linux/macOS). To do this in IntelliJ, you have to select your root folder in the **Project** window and the go to *File* -> *File Properties* -> *Line Separators* -> *LF - Unix and macOS (\n)*

Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433448/443233)

Comment: To turn off this auto-covert feature: https://gist.github.com/NateWeiler/df202280ce8cc38e9f00dbc17708fab2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value of **TAG** is proper. Check if container is getting launch or not using following command;

```
docker ps -a
```

Use an ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD and then you can use command line options in the docker run like in your example.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "Prepare_Dataset/server_engine/server.py"]
```

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766638/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-python-script-running-in-docker/35778013)

Comment: I have verified, TAG value is correct and it is launched. Using ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD is not making any change.I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

If others stumble across this, I hit the same error.  But my issue was different:

```
# Error `No such file or directory`

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "{$APP}"]

# Success

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "$APP"]
```

Comment: `${VAR}` is how you do brackets in bash.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error for no such file or directory.

To I actually made the mistake I named "DockeFile"

But it should be "Dockefile"

Now it working ( I set up for React projects)

My step  (For windows)

1. Docker engine should be running
2. Then install wsl-- update wsl--install
3. Now my command working